# Odd Mysql innoDB indexes issue

Tags: mysql, innodb, indexing

I'm having an issue debugging a problem with my innodb table.

I have a very powerful machine 32 core xenon setup, 72gb ram, 8 sas drives raid 10. Hardware is not the issue :) Entire db is loaded in the innodb buffer pool also. In general on all my databases on this machine everything is going lightning fast.

**My issue:**

I have a table with about 6 million rows.

```
site_id, site_domain, site_date, site_ip, etc etc
```

I have added indexes to site_id, site_domain, site_date and a few other columns. [all indexes screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKAwY.png)

`site_date` is a `INT (11)` column where I store timestamps. Very basic stuff.

The problem I'm having is when I run a simple query to get some results and I use `ORDER BY site_date DESC`.

The site_date column is making it super slow somehow, BUT only with some ID's, which confuses the hell out of me.

```
Example: (7812 being a slow ID here)

    SELECT site_domain
    FROM sites
    WHERE site_isp_id =  '7812'
    ORDER BY site_date DESC 
    LIMIT 10

Results: (95524 total, Query took 1.7469 sec)


Example: (7811 being a fast ID here)

    SELECT site_domain
    FROM sites
    WHERE site_isp_id =  '7811'
    ORDER BY site_date DESC 
    LIMIT 10

Results: (97599 total, Query took 0.0015 sec)
```

As you can see, for some odd reason using certain ID's it become very slow, and it seem to me like it's not using the indexes properly. I have tried to remove and re-add both the `site_isp_id` and `site_date` indexes, but this didn't fix anything. Also, if i do not ORDER BY `site_date` but `site_id` instead, it's always fast, so `site_date` seems to be the issue here.

Comment: `explain` on both queries might help

Comment: Explain fast query: http://i.imgur.com/FVaCeTi.png Explain slow query: http://i.imgur.com/EVwBeJM.png I do not see much difference.

Comment: Seems mysql is using the `site_date` index but not `site_isp_id` one. I would try a new index on column `(site_isp_id, site_date)` and see if it's better.

Comment: I have removed and re-added those 2 indexes already, same issue :(

Comment: To add to the issue, it's only slow when doing order by site_date DESC. When using ASC instead it's fast. But this doesn't solve my problem. ASC takes 0.001 sec DESC takes nearly 2 seconds.

Comment: I was advising to add an index on both column not remove existing ones

Comment: Sorry I do not follow. I already had those indexes as shown in the original post. Why add them again?

Comment: Add a **new** index on **2** columns: `site_isp_id` and `site_date`

Comment: Ok. I have done that now: http://i.imgur.com/xpPY0pF.png but now the same query takes nearly 3 seconds. So this isn't helping I'm afraid.

Comment: try with 1.`site_isp_id` and 2.`site_date`in this order (column order matters in indexes)

Comment: YES! that did the trick. Thank you so much for stick with me :)

Comment: I will add this proposal as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new index on the two columns `site_isp_id` and `site_date`, **in this order**, should help.